# AngularJS - How to return object in case nested http.get request

Tags: angularjs, http, get, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I have a problem with AngularJS is that, i cannot assign a value to an outer variable in the $http.get method. Here is my code snippet:

```
.factory('MediaService',['$http', function($http, $q){
    return {
        getGalleryIds : function() {
            galeriURL = 'http://api.tika.gov.tr/www/tr/galleries?';
            return $http.get(galeriURL, { cache: true}).then(function(response){
                contentIdList = response.data.data;
                var contentList = [];
                for (i=0;i<contentIdList.length;i++) {
                    var galeriContentURL = 'http://api.tika.gov.tr/www/tr/galleries/' + contentIdList[i].id;
                    contentList[i] = $http.get(galeriContentURL, { cache: true})
                        .then(function(response){
                            return response.data;
                        });
                }
                console.log(contentList);
                return contentList;
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

My problem is at **console.log(contentList);** line I'm getting **Promise Array** because of I cannot assign a value to outer variable.

```
[Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise]
```

How can I assign value to **var contentList = [ ];** variable in **for loop $$http.get** and at line **console.log(contentList);** get **Object Array** as follows

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies within this part:

```
contentList[i] = $http.get(galeriContentURL, { cache: true})
                        .then(function(response){
                            return response.data;
                        });
```

> `$http` returns a `promise` which you are storing in `contentList`
>   array, and not the data., when you use a return inside the success
>   function, the data will not be returned to content list.

---

You need to replace that code with this:

```
 $http.get(galeriContentURL, { cache: true})
                        .then(function(response){
                            contentList[i] = response.data;
                        });
```

> This does not eally guarantee that all the data objects stored in
>   array will be in the same order as the order in which they are
>   requested.

Comment: Thanks for answer but this is not working for me, because at line **console.log(contentList);** I'm getting a null array. Before return at console i'm reading **[ ]** not **[Object,Object]**.

Comment: @ozhanli:: yes then there is some other problem when you return the data from that url. can you try `console.log(response)` inside your `then()` function

Comment: no there is no problem with data from url. when i use console.log as http.get().then(){console.log} i'm getting object.

Comment: Also if I populate **contentList** as in question I'm getting promise but I need Object instead Promise

Comment: @ozhanli **promise will be always returned by `$http`**: try this `contentList.push(response);`, instead of `contentList[i] = response.data;` in my answer, should work :)

Comment: Thanks @Naeem but this will not hep me :( . Is there a way to populate an outer variable in promise function?

Comment: I would help you if you create a plunkr

Comment: I try to create a plnkr, but i think i cannot achieve :)   link to [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ruCSjdUM6KHsIUOqti0B?p=preview). I want to fetch all ids from api and list them in html.